# two Listviews inside tabview don't work as expected

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I have a code sharing Nativescript-Angular project. I am using two `ListView's` in a Lazy loaded module. The lazy loaded module is structured such that when I navigate to that module from AppModule.

```
<TabView id="tabViewContainer">
    <page-router-outlet  actionBarVisibility="never"  *tabItem="{title: 'Players'}" name="playersTab"></page-router-outlet>
    <page-router-outlet  actionBarVisibility="never" *tabItem="{title: 'Event Requests'}" name="eventRequestsTab"></page-router-outlet>
</TabView>
```

Now each tab item is a `page-router-outlet` which routes to a child component and that child 
component has `ListView` as parent element as shown below.

```
<ListView
  class="list-group"
  [items]="players"

  (loaded)="onListViewLoaded($event)"
  #listView
>
  <ng-template let-player="item" let-third="third">
    <GridLayout class="list-group-item" rows="*" columns="auto, *">
      <Image
      col="0"
      [src]="player.photoURL"
      class="thumb img-circle"
    ></Image>
      <StackLayout col="1">
        <Label
          [text]="player.displayName"
          class="list-group-item-heading"
        ></Label>
        <Label
          [text]="player.uid"
          class="list-group-item-text"
          textWrap="true"
        ></Label>
      </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
  </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Now the problem I am facing is when these two list views are shown side by side sometimes both the list views don't show anything and sometimes only the second tab shows data where as the first tab only shows the item dividers as shown below:-

**Case 1 tab-1**
[image]

**Case 1 tab-2**
[image]

**Case 2 tab-1**
[image: Case 2-picture-1]

**Case 2 tab-2**
[image: Case 2-picture-2]

The items always have more than one element but still this problem is being arised.

I have tried using the function `listview.refresh()` but still no success with that. I have also used `ChangedDetectionStratergy.OnPush` and called `markedForRefresh` function when data is received. I have tried using `ObservableArray` provided by `Nativescript` but I was bit confused while using that and also I felt it was not available for code sharing project.

I am frustrated since yesterday and it looks like a bug in Nativescript. Can you help overcome it so that both tabs shows the data always(knowing the arrays always have atleast one element) ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: @Narendra No, I stopped using Nativescript because debugging was a nightmare for me.

Answer (score 0):

Two listview is working inside tabView for example:-

**app.component.html :-**

```
`<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">

<page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Home', iconSource: getIconSource('home')}"
    name="homeTab">
</page-router-outlet>

<page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Browse', iconSource: getIconSource('browse')}"
    name="browseTab">
</page-router-outlet>

</TabView>`
```

**app.component.ts:-**

```
`import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

 import { isAndroid } from "tns-core-modules/platform";

@Component({
selector: "ns-app",

moduleId: module.id,

templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {
    // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Init your component properties here.
}

getIconSource(icon: string): string {
    const iconPrefix = isAndroid ? "res://" : "res://tabIcons/";

    return iconPrefix + icon;
}
}
```

`
**app.module.ts :-**

```
`import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
 import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
],
imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    AppRoutingModule
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`

**app.routing.ts :-**

```
`import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { NSEmptyOutletComponent } from "nativescript-angular";

import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "",

    redirectTo: "/(homeTab:home/default//browseTab:browse/default)",

    pathMatch: "full"
},

{
    path: "home",

    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,

    loadChildren: "~/app/home/home.module#HomeModule",

    outlet: "homeTab"
},
{
    path: "browse",

    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,

    loadChildren: "~/app/browse/browse.module#BrowseModule",

    outlet: "browseTab"
}
];

@NgModule({

imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],

exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`

**home.component.html :-**

```
`<GridLayout class="page page-content">

<ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">

    <ng-template let-item="item">

        <ScrollView height="150">

            <Label [text]="item.name" class="list-group-item"></Label>

        </ScrollView>

    </ng-template>

</ListView>

</GridLayout>`
```

**home.component.ts:-**

```
`import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService, IDataItem } from "../shared/data.service";

@Component({
selector: "Home",
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

items: Array<IDataItem>;

constructor(private _itemService: DataService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this._itemService.getItems();
}
}`
```

**home.module.ts:-**

```
`import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";

import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";

import { HomeRoutingModule } from "./home-routing.module";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";

import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./item-detail/item-detail.component";

@NgModule({

imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
],

declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    ItemDetailComponent
],

schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
]

})

export class HomeModule { }`
```

**home-routing.module.ts:-**

```
`import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";

import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./item-detail/item-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [

{ path: "default", component: HomeComponent },

{ path: "item/:id", component: ItemDetailComponent }

];

@NgModule({

imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],

exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]

})

export class HomeRoutingModule { }`
```

**browse.component.html :-**

```
`<GridLayout class="page page-content">

<ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">

    <ng-template let-item="item">

        <ScrollView height="150">

            <Label [text]="item.name" class="list-group-item"></Label>

        </ScrollView>

    </ng-template>

</ListView>

</GridLayout>`
```

**browse.component.ts:-**

```
`import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService, IDataItem } from "../shared/data.service";

@Component({
selector: "Browse",
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: "./browse.component.html"
})
export class BrowseComponent implements OnInit {

items: Array<IDataItem>;

constructor(private _itemService: DataService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this._itemService.getItems();
}
}
```

`

**browse.module.ts:-**

```
`import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";

import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";

import { BrowseRoutingModule } from "./browse-routing.module";

import { BrowseComponent } from "./browse.component";

import { DataService } from "../shared/data.service";

@NgModule({
imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    BrowseRoutingModule
],
declarations: [
    BrowseComponent
],
schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
],
providers:[
    DataService
]
})
export class BrowseModule { }`
```

**browse-routing.module.ts:-**

```
`import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { BrowseComponent } from "./browse.component";

const routes: Routes = [

{ path: "default", component: BrowseComponent }

];

@NgModule({

imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],

exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]

})

export class BrowseRoutingModule { }
```

`

Example Available On Here:- 
[Nativescript playground url](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=85KCiX&v=2)

Comment: That playground example does not show anything on ios. I have not tested on android.